# ffmpeg "dynamic" image overlay

Tags: qt, ffmpeg, udp, overlay, live-streaming

So, i'm currently developing and application (with Qt) that get image from a capture board. Well, the problem is that i need to get the ffmpeg image livestream. I'm able to display the video and my image overlay but i need to change that image in run time. Does anyone know how to solve it?

I'm using local udp output for the video. Thanks for the attention.

My ffmpeg command:  `ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -i /home/gimenez/Desktop/imageTest.png -filter_complex \"[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,10,20)'\" -v 0 -vcodec mpeg4 -f mpegts udp://192.168.100.63:23000?pkt_size=1316`

Comment: Are you overwriting the image file during exec?

Comment: Ok.. i tried a lot of examples and got to a "solution" but not the best
I save a .png file and play as stream, after that, my live stream overlay my /dev/video0 with that udp stream and then output also as udp

Comment: the problem is that in order to change my image i have to close that process and run it again

Comment: the initial tought was to overwrite the image and ffmpeg display that change

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: Gyan, i'm currently off work. All code and information is at company computer
As soon as i i get there i post the two ffmpeg process i use 
Anyhow... I really appreciate all the help so far, thanks!
Have a good weekend

Comment: Hi, @Gyan.. so i'm testing my steam with "ffplay -codec:a:1 vp8 udp://192.168.100.63:23001"


my image loot is with "ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -s 1280x720 -r 30 -i "/home/gimenez/Desktop/imageTest.png" -vcodec mpeg4 -f mpegts udp://192.168.100.63:23000"


And my 'final'stream is: "ffmpeg -i "/dev/video0" -i "udp://192.168.100.63:23000" -filter_complex '[1:v]colorkey=0x000000:0.3:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]' -map '[out]' -c:v libvpx -b:v 2000k -auto-alt-ref 0 -f webm udp://192.168.100.63:23001"

Comment: I'm also having a very delayed stream :/ but didnt found if the delay is caused by ffplay or the stream upload (if its ffplay theres no problem because i'm gonna use a self-made player)

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add dynamic image overlay on live stream video input? Means we can keep changing image overlay after video stream started?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I tried to solve. In the beginning, I tried to work it out with FFMPEG, but then I found my solution in OpenCV & CVzone (which uses OpenCV and Mediapipe). In the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voRFbl-GKGY) [32:24] you can see an example of changing the parameters of the frames live. Hopefully, you already solved that problem, but maybe this solution will help others in the future!